# how to export from Eclipse C running on embedded target out to a text file (on Windows)

Tags: eclipse

I'm running a benchmark on Eclipse debugger and want the text output to export out to a text file on Windows.

Eclipse debugger is running on an Ambiq embedded chip evaluation board.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse > Run menu > Debug Configurations > Common tab > select and enter Output File path & name.

All stdout (ie. fwrite, printf) will now go into the file instead of Console window.